# Не работает картинка-ссылка html

Tags: html, css

Не работает картинка-ссылка на сайте, хотя написано вроде правильно и даже через инструменты разработчика можно эту ссылку увидеть.

Что странно:
Ещё две ссылки-картинки на сайте тоже не работают. Работает только одна в футере.
Но с планшета они почему-то работают.

ссылка на сайт: ???? (я ещё не установил нормальный сертификат безопасности, поэтому пишет предупреждение)

```html
<div class="sponsors">
  <p>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/c/-/featured" target="_blank">
      <img src="images/-.png" width="50" height="50" alt="-">
    </a>
    <a href="https://discord.gg/9wMvRc7t5sn" target="_blank">
      <img src="images/discord.png" width="50" height="50" alt="-">
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.-.com/members/-/projects" target="_blank">
      <img src="images/-.png" width="50" height="50" alt="-">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: В вашем примере все работает. 
Покажите пример где ссылка не работает.

Answer (score 0):

У блока с классом "sponsors" поменяйте z-index. Вы там нагородили, что другие блоки его перекрывают. Но тогда станут недоступны те ссылки что его перекрывают. Если нет желания сильно все менять, то можно сделать так:

```
div.sponsors img {
    margin-left: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
```

Это решит проблему с нажатием ссылок и ничего не поломает

Comment: Да, ещё как нагородил) Впервые за сайт взялся. Спасибо, попробую исправить!